# Есть ли встроенные функции шифрования в PHP?

Tags: php

Что-то самое простое, например:

Я ей строку + ключ шифрования она мне шифр

Я ей шифр + ключ, она мне снова строку

Ну плюс опция - что делать, зашифровать или расшифровать.

Видел самописные такие функции, но неужели нет ничего встроенного в язык?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.crypto.php https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413693/186083

Comment: @Visman в ответ однозначно!

Comment: `md5()` или `hash("sha1" ...)`

Comment: Да полно встроенных функций. Наслаждайтесь http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.crypto.php

Comment: @Duoxx md5() или hash("sha1" ...) - это не шифрование, а хеширование

Comment: Есть функция упаковки `pack` и распаковки `unpack`. А также целый движек `crypt`.