# Способы шифрования строки php

Tags: php, шифрование

Можете посоветовать способы шифрования на примерах php? Интересует вариант описанный тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480782/222744 ,насколько  надежный этот вариант. Есть ли способы надежней,лучше?Так же интересует способ повторного шифрования зашифрованной строки ,тем же методом,но другим ключем ?

Comment: Смотря что шифровать, используйте функцию `crypt(...)`.

Comment: В тех ответах, ссылку на которые вы дали есть полный пример как выполнять шифрование. Надежность зависит от используемого алгоритма (который передается первым параметром в mcrypt http://php.net/manual/ru/mcrypt.ciphers.php) и описана в интернете по каждому алгоритму отдельно. В общем случае они надежны. Что касается повторного шифрования другим ключом, рассматриваете результат после первого шифрования как входной текст и шифруете точно так же

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Надежное обратимое шифрование по шестнадцатеричному ключу.

```
// Encrypt Function
function mc_encrypt($encrypt, $key) {
  $encrypt = serialize($encrypt);
  $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
  $key = pack('H*', $key);
  $mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $encrypt, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
  $passcrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $encrypt.$mac, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
  $encoded = base64_encode($passcrypt).'|'.base64_encode($iv);
  return $encoded;
}
```

---

```
// Decrypt Function
function mc_decrypt($decrypt, $key) {
  $decrypt = explode('|', $decrypt.'|');
  $decoded = base64_decode($decrypt[0]);
  $iv = base64_decode($decrypt[1]);
  if(strlen($iv)!==mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)){ return false; }
  $key = pack('H*', $key);
  $decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
  $mac = substr($decrypted, -64);
  $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -64);
  $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $decrypted, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
  if($calcmac!==$mac){ return false; }
  $decrypted = unserialize($decrypted);
  return $decrypted;
}
```

---

Пример использования:

---

```
define('ENCRYPTION_KEY', md5(microtime() . rand(0, 9999)));
$txt = 'Обратимое шифрование на php';
$encrypted = mc_encrypt($txt, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
$decrypted = mc_decrypt($encrypted, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
```

Comment: про обратимое шифрование не сказано не слова.

Comment: @And >> `Можете посоветовать способы шифрования на примерах php`<< в чём проблема ?

Comment: Непонятно что шифровать и для какой цели это нужно. Пожалуйста прочитайте комментарий к вопросу.

Comment: @And если шифрование необратимо - то это уже не шифрование,  а хэширование.

Comment: Вы же сами говорите, что хеширование, а пишите о шифровании. Шифр и хеш, разные вещи.